# pgfplot error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number

Tags: pgfplots, errors

I'm trying to plot some points in a diagram.

The idea is that three different workers with some bundle of A and B labour can choose to be or not to be in an occupation. The eight allocations are the eight different ways in which these workers can sort themselves in or out of the occupation.

The code is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,thick]
            \def\LA{1}        % Total amount of A labour
             \def\LB{1}       % Total amount of B labour

        % three workers with different amounts of A and B labour
            \def\oneA{0.3}
            \def\twoA{0.5}
            \def\threeA{\LA-\oneA-\twoA}
            \def\oneB{0.6}
            \def\twoB{0.1}
            \def\threeB{\LB-\oneB-\twoB}

        % eight allocations:
        \def\aA{0}        % no workers in the occupation
        \def\aB{0}
        \def\bA{\oneA}    % worker one in the occupation
        \def\bB{\oneB}  
        \def\cA{\twoA}    % worker two in the occupation
        \def\cB{\twoB}
        \def\dA{\threeA}  % worker three in the occupation
        \def\dB{\threeB}    
        \def\eA{\oneA + \twoA}      % workers one + two in the occupation
        \def\eB{\oneB + \twoB}
        \def\fA{\oneA + \threeA}    % workers one + three in the occupation
        \def\fB{\oneB + \threeB}    
        \def\gA{\twoA + \threeA}   % workers two+ three in the occupation
        \def\gB{\twoA + \threeA}
        \def\hA{\LA}               % all workers in the occupation
        \def\hB{\LB}



         \begin{axis}[
              restrict y to domain=0:\LB,
              %samples = 100,           
              xmin = 0, xmax = \LA,
              ymin = 0, ymax = \LB,
              xlabel = $L_1^A$,
              ylabel = $L_1^B$,
              axis y line = left,    
              axis x line = bottom,
              y axis line style = {-}, 
              x axis line style = {-}
            ]

    \addplot+[nodes near coords,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic]
    table[meta=label] {
    x               y                   label
    {\aA}           {\aB}                   a
    {\bA}           {\bB}                   b
    {\cA}           {\cB}                   c
    {\dA}           {\dB}                   d
    {\eA}           {\eB}                   e
    {\fA}           {\fB}                   f
    {\gA}           {\gB}                   g
    {\hA}           {\hB}                   h
    };

         \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I get the following error message:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '1-0.6-0.1' as a floating point
number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '-0.6-0.1'..
```

If I comment out lines, I find that the three first allocations work (i.e. a, b and c work), but when I try the fourth allocation (d), it cannot handle the difference 1-0.6-0.1 that I have defined in \threeA.

I am super grateful for any help!

Thanks!

Sofia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I did not test this because I currently don't have access to my computer and I don't have a compilable MWE)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,thick]
            \pgfmathsetmacro\LA{1}        % Total amount of A labour
             \pgfmathsetmacro\LB{1}       % Total amount of B labour

        % three workers with different amounts of A and B labour
            \pgfmathsetmacro\oneA{0.3}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\twoA{0.5}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\threeA{\LA-\oneA-\twoA}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\oneB{0.6}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\twoB{0.1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\threeB{\LB-\oneB-\twoB}

        % eight allocations:
        \pgfmathsetmacro\aA{0}        % no workers in the occupation
        \pgfmathsetmacro\aB{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bA{\oneA}    % worker one in the occupation
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bB{\oneB}  
        \pgfmathsetmacro\cA{\twoA}    % worker two in the occupation
        \pgfmathsetmacro\cB{\twoB}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\dA{\threeA}  % worker three in the occupation
        \pgfmathsetmacro\dB{\threeB}    
        \pgfmathsetmacro\eA{\oneA + \twoA}      % workers one + two in the occupation
        \pgfmathsetmacro\eB{\oneB + \twoB}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\fA{\oneA + \threeA}    % workers one + three in the occupation
        \pgfmathsetmacro\fB{\oneB + \threeB}    
        \pgfmathsetmacro\gA{\twoA + \threeA}   % workers two+ three in the occupation
        \pgfmathsetmacro\gB{\twoA + \threeA}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\hA{\LA}               % all workers in the occupation
        \pgfmathsetmacro\hB{\LB}



         \begin{axis}[
              restrict y to domain=0:\LB,
              %samples = 100,           
              xmin = 0, xmax = \LA,
              ymin = 0, ymax = \LB,
              xlabel = $L_1^A$,
              ylabel = $L_1^B$,
              axis y line = left,    
              axis x line = bottom,
              y axis line style = {-}, 
              x axis line style = {-}
            ]

    \addplot+[nodes near coords,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic]
    table[meta=label] {
    x               y                   label
    {\aA}           {\aB}                   a
    {\bA}           {\bB}                   b
    {\cA}           {\cB}                   c
    {\dA}           {\dB}                   d
    {\eA}           {\eB}                   e
    {\fA}           {\fB}                   f
    {\gA}           {\gB}                   g
    {\hA}           {\hB}                   h
    };

         \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You can not simply perform maths using `\def`. In the code above, I use computing commands from `pgfmath`.

Comment: yippie! Thank you so much!

Comment: @SofiaH Glad to help! If this answer helps you solve the problem, please consider accepting it.